# What are the rules for China's visa-free transit programs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, china, visa-free-entry

Assuming one wants to travel through China, what are the rules for visa-free access? To be more specific:

- How does the 24-hour visa free transit work?
- How does the 72-hour version work?
- What does a person ineligible for either of these programs have to do to transit China?
- Do the programs apply to flights only or do they also work for transit on land?
- Would a visitor save much hassle by using visa free transit instead of just getting a visa?

> NB: this is intended as a canonical question on transiting China

Comment: @Coke great thanks for editing both posts. Guangzhou is next apparently, but not sure when.

Comment: @mts Will be monitoring Timatic as closely as I have time to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**WARNING: Timatic has experienced a major overhaul. There are some inconsistencies, and I'm going to clear them up with my IATA contact, after which this answer will be updated.**

The following is taken from Timatic, the database used by airlines (wording occasionally modified by myself to make it more understandable).

The following quotes address the question: **who can transit without a visa, and under what conditions?**

**General restrictions**:

> - Transit without visa (TWOV) is **not** possible at Fuzhou
>     (FOC), Huangshan (TXN), Mudanjiang (MDG), Shenzhen (SZX)
>     and Yanji (YNJ).
> - For transit without visa (TWOV) purposes, the USA territories of Guam or Northern Mariana Islands do **not** count as third countries in relation to the USA. Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan, however, **do** in relation to China.
> - Passengers with a
>     British National (Overseas) passport
>     must hold a Mainland Travel Permit for Hong
>     Kong and Macao Residents (Hui Xiang Zheng, credit-card
>     format) together with their Hong Kong ID

**For Hong Kong/Macau/Taiwan passport holders**

- **Hong Kong/Macau passport holders**

  > Passengers holding
  >   confirmed onward airline tickets to a third country, in
  >   transit through Guangzhou (CAN), Shanghai Pudong (PVG) or
  >   Beijing (PEK), for a maximum transit time of 24 hours.
- **Taiwan passport holders**

  > Passengers holding confirmed onward airline
  >   tickets to a third country, in transit through Beijing
  >   (PEK), for a maximum transit time of 24 hours.

**If Urumqi is the first transit point**

> Holders of confirmed onward airline tickets, in transit
>     through Urumqi (URC), for a max. transit time
>     of 2 hours. Transit incl. multiple stops within China
>     (People's Rep.), with a total transit time of max. 24 hours,
>     is permitted.
>
> This does **not** apply to nationals of nationals of
>      Afghanistan, Azerbaijan, Hong Kong, Iran, Iraq, Kazakhstan,
>      Kyrgyzstan, Macau, Malaysia, Nigeria, Oman, Pakistan, Syria,
>      Saudia Arabia, Sri Lanka, Taiwan, Thailand, Turkey, United Arab
>      Emirates and Yemen.

**In all other cases**

- **24-hour rule (except at Guangzhou)**

  > Holders of confirmed onward air, cruise or train tickets for
  >   a max. transit time of 24 hours. Transit
  >   incl. multiple stops within China (People's Rep.), with a
  >   total transit time of max. 24 hours, is permitted. They must
  >   travel to a third country.
  >
  > This does **not** apply to nationals of Malaysia with a normal
  >   passport in transit through Xiamen (XMN).
  >
  > Nationals of Canada and USA are **not** permitted to use the
  >   multiple-stop transit within China, if transiting through
  >   Weihai (WEH) or Wuhan (WUH).
- **24-hour rule (at Guangzhou)**

  > Holders of confirmed onward air tickets in transit through
  >   Guangzhou (CAN) to a third country, for a max.
  >   transit time of 24 hours.
  >
  > This does **not** apply to nationals of Syria.
  >
  > Transit incl. multiple stops within China (People's Rep.)
  >   is permitted at Guangzhou (CAN) only when the first transit
  >   point is Beijing (PEK). The total maximum transit time is
  >   24 hours.
- **72-hour rule**

  > Nationals of Albania, Argentina, Australia, Austria,
  >   Belarus, Belgium, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Brazil, Bulgaria,
  >   Canada, Chile, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark,
  >   Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
  >   Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Korea (Rep.), Latvia, Lithuania,
  >   Luxembourg, Macedonia (FYROM), Malta, Mexico, Monaco,
  >   Montenegro, Netherlands, New Zealand, Poland, Portugal,
  >   Qatar, Romania, Russian Fed., Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia,
  >   Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA, Ukraine, United Arab
  >   Emirates and United Kingdom holding confirmed onward airline tickets departing
  >   directly to a third country, **if arriving in and departing
  >   from the same city**:
  >
  > - Changsha (CSX), Chengdu (CTU), Chongqing (CKG), Dalian
  >     (DLC), Guangzhou (CAN), Qingdao (TAO), Wuhan
  >     (WUH), Xi'an (XIY) or Xiamen (XMN) for a max. transit time
  >     of 72 hours, starting from 00:01 on the day following the
  >     day of entry.
  > - Guilin (KWL), Harbin (HRB), Kunming
  >     (KMG), or Shenyang (SHE) for a max. transit time of 72
  >     hours;
- **144-hour rule**

  > Nationals of Albania, Argentina, Australia, Austria,
  >   Belarus, Belgium, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Brazil, Bulgaria,
  >   Canada, Chile, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark,
  >   Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland,
  >   Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Korea (Rep.), Latvia, Lithuania,
  >   Luxembourg, Macedonia (FYROM), Malta, Mexico, Monaco,
  >   Montenegro, Netherlands, New Zealand, Poland, Portugal,
  >   Qatar, Romania, Russian Fed., Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia,
  >   Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA, Ukraine, United Arab
  >   Emirates and United Kingdom, holding confirmed onward air, cruise or train
  >   tickets to a third country, arriving in and departing from
  >   any one of the following locations (**same region required**) for a maximum of 144 hours, starting from 00:01 on the day following the day of entry.:
  >
  > - Region A: Beijing (PEK), Tianjin
  >     (TSN), Shijiazhuang (SJW), Beijing West Railway Station,
  >     Tianjin International Cruise Home Port, Qinhuangdao Sea
  >     Port
  > - Region B: Hangzhou (HGH), Nanjing Lukou (NKG), Shanghai Hongqiao (SHA), Shanghai Pudong (PVG), Shanghai Port International Cruise Terminal, Shanghai Wusongkou (Baoshan) International Cruise Terminal, Shanghai Railway Station

Comment: "Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan, however, do in relation to China." But not Hainan?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Hainan is not a separate country for border pusposes.

Comment: @Cole Thank you. It also appears that visa on arrival can't be obtained in Hainan after any transit via a Chinese airport...

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov There's been lots of changes I now see. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm flying from Malaysia to Kazakhstan via Guangzhou and Urumqi in a couple of days. After emailing and calling China Southern, the Chinese embassy in Kuala Lumpur and the Chinese consulate in Kota Kinabalu, I still don't have a definitive answer as to whether a visa is required or not. All of them said to get a transit visa "just to be safe", which I've done now.

I interpreted Timatic the same way Coke did, but didn't want to take any risks. I do believe "If Urumqi is the **first** transit point" are Coke's words, because that doesn't seem to be explicit on Timatic. I'll update [my post](http://sixwheelseast.com/post/171957730381/china-24-hours-transit-without-visa-guangzhou-urumqi) after the flights, if I learn anything more than stated already.

Edit: It turns out China Southern has a transfer lounge at Urumqi. When we arrived at 13h30, there even was a free lunch buffet. They seem to want to keep you here until 2 hours before the flight out of Urumqi. I assume this is to meet the 2 hour Transit Without Visa rule for Urumqi. In other words, I believe that a visa isn't needed, as long as you apply for the TWOV at your first airport in China.