# Can I transit through Guangzhou into Beijing from Melbourne to Almaty and still get visa-free transit?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork, china

My current plan is to go from Melbourne, Australia to Almaty, Kazakhstan. I am an Australian citizen. The flight itinerary is shown below, but it transits through Guangzhou and I noted that Wikipedia (not the best source) [says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#72-hour_stay_/_144-hour_stay):

> both flights must have no stopovers of any kind within Mainland China
>   prior to arrival or after departure at the port of entry, and the
>   outbound flight's first stop or destination must be in a different
>   country than the inbound flight's

However, I am assuming that since I don't officially pass Chinese Immigration until Beijing, this doesn't count. But can someone confirm this?

Also do the times match up for the 144-hour visa?

In Kazakhstan I can get a visa on arrival.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106266/what-are-the-rules-for-chinas-visa-free-transit-programs

Answer (score 2):

You're not eligible for the 144-hour visa exemption, as you would need:

- to be entering China in GZ; *You're not.*
- and leaving China from somewhere in Guangdong. *You're not.*

In Beijing you are probably not eligible for the 72-hour visa exemption, as you're arriving from a Chinese city.

However, since you arrive in CAN at 15:20 and leave PEK at 05:55 (+1), you are eligible for [24-hour transit without a visa](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm).

Comment: If you don't pass customs isn't your entry given in Beijing?

Comment: No. For the purpose of the 74/144-hour visa, there can be only one stop within China. You must arrive from overseas, and leave to a third country, directly.

Comment: [and it's Immigration, not Customs. Customs are the guys checking your luggage, whereas Immigration are police, checking your passport and documents].

Comment: OP does not qualify for the 24h rules as he intends to stay for six days between flights. There are additional restrictions for 24h visa-free transit in CAN apparently.

Comment: You're right. I didn't check the dates carefully, and automatically assumed it the Beijing - Almaty flight was the next day.

Comment: And in Beijing you only get 72 hours anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the first bullet point either, they are entering China in CAN. Beijing has expanded from 72h to 144h as of 28 Dec 2017. CAN plans to but is still only 72h.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, guess it's not worth the trouble in that case.

Comment: @atx You'll clear Immigration in Guangzhou; see my answer

Comment: Hi @Coke, thanks - I wanted to stay in Beijing for a few days though, it was going to be one of the highlights of my trip.

Comment: Getting a Chinese visa isn't that hard or expensive, though...

Comment: Probably not, I read that it was quite cheap, but who the hell wants to go fill out forms? Visa on arrival is so much nicer

Comment: @atx It wouldn't have been a visa on Arrival, but visa-free entry. Same as in Kazakhstan - you don't need  visa there at all

Comment: Well plenty of people fill out forms every day... A visa on arrival usually requires to fill out a form. You were hoping for a visa exemption, which isn't a VoA, AND you have to fill out an immigration form anyway...

Comment: @Coke yeh, precisely. I was just explaining that in the context of getting visas, getting one on arrival is better than going to the embassy / consulate (4 days processing) or getting one online. Not to mention it seems absurd that I'd even pay extra just because I'll transit within an hour onwards to Beijing.

Comment: @dda, you just can't escape the form-filling can you? hahaha damn

Comment: @atx What you get on arrival is an entry stamp, not a visa. An actual visa on arrival is something you get at a separate desk before clearing immigration (where you'll *additionally* receive an entry stamp). China and Kazakhstan both issue them if pre-approved, which however doesn't apply to you. But I digress...

Comment: Yeh I haven't been saying the right thing here, I think Australians are actually visa-free.

Comment: @atx Checked the procedure for the G visa, it's pretty painless. There are several Chinese consulates in AU - check which one covers your place of residence. Make sure to apply for a double-entry visa if entering China on your return **unless** it's for less than 24 hours **or** between 24 and 144 hours if, for example, both arriving in and departing China through Beijing

Answer (score 1):

**You will need a Chinese transit (type G) visa**

> However, I am assuming that since I don't officially pass Chinese Immigration until Beijing...

That's wrong: you'll clear immigration in Guangzhou, then catch the Beijing flight from the domestic sector. And if flying domestically in transit, you can remain in China no longer than 24 hours, whereas you're staying for 6 days.

So again, you need at least a transit visa. It can be issued as a single or double-entry visa for a stay of max 10 days per entry.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr: you need a visa for the proposed itinerary.

We have a general thread for visa-free transit in China: [What are the rules for China's visa-free transit programs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106266/32134)

Your itinerary does not work out for a number of reasons:

- you are passing immigration in China, wherever your first stop is, i.e. in your case CAN. That is also what counts for the visa-free transit rules.
- For 72h/144h visa-free transit, you need to transit from a direct flight from abroad (country A) to another direct flight to abroad (country B) while staying in the same city/region, i.e. no domestic connecting flights.
- you could qualify for 24h visa-free transit (where the regional restrictions are lifted, **though see the added restrictions for Guangzhou in the linked post**), but for this your planned stay of about six days is too long.

Therefore you require a visa, or you would need to enter Beijing on a direct flight from abroad.