# Do stateless people need a visa for a layover in China?

Tags: transit-visas, china, layovers, stateless-persons, can

I'm flying to Thailand with a US Travel Document and a visa for Thailand. I have a 7-hour layover in China. Should I be good with the 24-hour China visa exemption or should I attempt to get a visa for China (or e-visa) since I'm a US permanent resident and not a US citizen, just for the layover? Thank you.

My Current nationality is Stateless (parents were refugees from USSR in the early 90's).  I wish to layover at  Guangzhou Baiyun International Airport (CAN).

Comment: What is your citizenship and in which airport is the layover?

Comment: Im a United States Permanent Resident in the process of becoming a Citizen. My Current nationality is Stateless (parents were refugees from USSR in the early 90's). Guangzhou Baiyun International Airport.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106266/32134 is related, but it does not answer your query as you are stateless and it all that really counts seems to be citizenship. If nobody comes up with a better answer, I would contact the Chinese embassy. Also https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/china/708095-china-24-72-144-hour-transit-without-visa-twov-rules-master-thread.html is useful. Stateless is not mentioned as an exclusion to 24h TWOV as far as I can tell.

Comment: Here is an Estonian visa agency http://www.viisa.ee/en/services/visa-issuing/visa-to-china that procures transit visa for stateless persons with permanent residency in Estonia, I would assume similar applies for you.

Answer (score 2):

A query through Timatic, the database used by airlines to check document requirements, a visa is necessary for passengers holding travel documents issued to stateless persons (or refugees or travel documents for aliens).

The [G Visa](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/hrsq/#G) is for those who transit through China, applied for at the [consular office](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/) that serves your area of residence (locations are Washington, DC; Chicago, IL; Houston, TX; Los Angeles, CA; New York, NY; San Francisco, CA). The regular processing time is about 4 working days.