# Routing Query - China and Mongolia from India

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, china, mongolia

My traveller is an Indian passport holder and he has a single-entry Chinese visa for a month.

His routing is as follows:
Delhi (DEL) -x Guangzhou (CAN) - Beijing (PEK) // (Surface) //  Ulaanbatar (ULN) -x Guangzhou (CAN) -x Beijing (PEK) - Delhi (DEL)

Once he enters China, he will apply for a one-month Mongolia visa in China.

While returning to India, his flight from ULN to DEL has to stop in China. Does he require a China visa or a transit visa?

Comment: I would presume that "single entry" means "single entry", i.e., he can only enter China once and will require a separate visa for the return trip.  But there might be caveats & exceptions that I don't know about.

Comment: I presume there's an error in your return flight routing (ULN-CAN-PEK-DEL does not quite seem very logical), but is the actual routing ULN-PEK-CAN-DEL (which means you definitely need some sort of visa) or a simpler ULN-PEK-DEL or ULN-CAN-DEL (in which case you might not need a visa at all)?

Comment: So I feel we agree that he is fine on first segment up to Beijing (he will enter in China in CAN). On the way back, I side with @jcaron - a quick search gives no direct flights from ULN to CAN. If the return itinerary is ULN -> PEK -> CAN -> DEL and the arrival to PEK until the departure from CAN is less than 24h he should be fine (see answer linked in a separate comment). If the routing is as you write, then he will need a visa.

Comment: Posting this link as a separate comment so my comment above remains in case this question gets closed as a duplicate: [What are the rules for China's visa-free transit programs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106266/32134)

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.